# python upload large files - Error: Message 413 Request Entity Too Large - ignores 100-continue

Tags: python, file-upload

I've written this code to upload files to 3rd. party ResApi server. The code works as expected for small files, but as soon as I try to upload files larger than 100MB then fails.

Here is my code and error below:

```
import sys, os
from requests import Request, Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder
import ssl

from subprocess import *
        
class SSLAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    '''An HTTPS Transport Adapter that uses an arbitrary SSL version.'''
    def __init__(self, ssl_version=None, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_version = ssl_version
        super(SSLAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=self.ssl_version)   


class FileBoxRequest:
    def __init__(self):      

        self.ca_file='trustedca.pem'
        self.cert_file='TECHUSER.cer'
        self.key_file='TECHUSER.key'
        
    def sendFile(self, my1GBFile):
        
        self.base_url = 'https://myserver.com/fileBoxServer/api/ssl/files/upload';
                                                                                                                        
        s = Session()
        #s.headers.update({'Expect': '100-continue'})
        s.mount('https://', SSLAdapter(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2))
        multipart_data = MultipartEncoder(fields={ 
                'file': ('my1GBFile.txt', open(my1GBFile, 'rb'), 'text/plain') 
                }
            )
        #req = Request('POST', self.base_url, data=multipart_data,headers={'Content-Type': multipart_data.content_type,'Accept': 'application/json','Expect': '100-continue'})
        req = Request('POST', self.base_url, data=multipart_data,headers={'Content-Type': multipart_data.content_type,'Accept': 'application/json'})        
        prepped = req.prepare()
        print('Sending filebox...')  
        
        r = s.send(prepped,
           verify=self.ca_file,
           cert=(self.cert_file, self.key_file),
           timeout=54000 #90 minutes
         )
        if r.ok:
            cookies = dict(r.cookies)
            print("cookies: ", cookies)
        else:
            print("Error: HTTP %i - %s, Message %s" % (r.status_code, r.reason, r.text))
```

> Message: HTTP 413 - Request Entity Too Large.
>  The requested
> resource /fileBoxServer/api/ssl/files/upload  does not allow request
> data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request
> exceeds the capacity limit.

Checking with the engineering team of the RES API suggested to add header={'Expect': '100-continue'} to the request.

But as soon as I add this header I get this error:

> File "../scripts\FileBoxRequest.py", line 79, in sendFile
> r = s.send(prepped,
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\jup385\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 655, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\jup385\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 498, in send
> raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
>
> ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(10053,
> 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host
> machine', None, 10053, None))

Adding the header to the session is seems to be ignored:

```
s.headers.update({'Expect': '100-continue'})
```

```
**This is python version:**
Python version
3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Version info.
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

I am sure, the problem is in my code of python client side, because I replicated this code perl and in DotNet C#, added the header **'Expect': '100-continue'** , in both scripts I upload files larger than 1GB successfully.

```
#Perl:
...
my $file_path = "OneGbFile.txt";
my $url = 'https://myserver.com/fileBoxServer/api/ssl/files/upload';
my $res = $ua->post($url,
    Content_Type => 'multipart/form-data',
    Accept => 'application/json',
    Expect => '100-continue'
    Content => [
        file => [$file_path],
    ],
);
```

//DotNet

```
...
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath);
    handler.ClientCertificates.Clear();
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
    handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
    handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Expect", "100-continue");
        using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            formData.Add(new StreamContent(fileInfo.OpenRead()), "file", fileInfo.Name);
            //string result = client.PostAsync("fileBoxServer/api/ssl/files/upload", formData).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            string result = client.PostAsync(base_url, formData).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            LogWriter(string.Format("Result: {0}", result));
        }
    }
}
```

An option could be so send the data by chunks, but apparently the ResApi service I am calling does not support this option.

Any help or suggestion is very welcome.

Comment: Have you instead tried the `MultipartEncoder(fields={'file': open(file_path, 'rb')})` syntax?

Comment: @rv.kvetch: I did. Like this was my original code and got the same error.
Thank you.